# Is there a specification for AAC-LC (de)compression?

Tags: audio, codec, aac, mpeg-4

Is there a specification that describe specifically the AAC-LC standard, and is it a realist goal to achieve a codec, not a general one, but for a specific AAC-LC format, with predefined number of channels and sample rate?

Are there some existing projects for AAC-LC specifically?

[EDIT]

I found a first project, coded with MatLab, that is looking promising:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28028-mpeg-4-aac-lc-decoder

It directly demux mp4, and decode AAC-LC with no blah-blah. Thousand of hardcoded values and box definitions. Maybe this is exactly built to test common iPhone/Windows Phone MP4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAC (Advanced Audio Coding), including the LC (Low Complexity) profile, was originally specified in ISO/IEC 13818-7 (MPEG-2 Part 7).  It was later updated by ISO/IEC 14496-3 (MPEG-4 Part 3); subpart 4 covers AAC specifically, and subpart 1 (Main) is likely to also be helpful.

General information can be found on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding).

There are a few existing open source implementations.  Currently one of the better quality ones is the [Fraunhofer FDK AAC Codec Library for Android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/fdk-aac/); it was released as open source as part of Android but is not Android-specific.  Its primary disadvantage is that its license is considered to be incompatible with the GPL.  Some other open source implementations are listed in [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)'s [AAC Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide), including FFmpeg's native AAC encoder, which is in development.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check this codec. I'm searching for a AAC-LC specific implementation, since code like isoparser, jcodec, and some other projects are often including MP4 demuxer (something I can achieve manually with a for-loop) with thousand of box classes, and are including a decoder with compatibility for about 10-12 AAC format, with some requiring extra-methods that AAC-LC doesn't require. It seems that implementing AAC-LC from scratch would be simpler than porting these codes

Comment: libfdk-aac does implement several AAC profiles, although the ffmpeg native AAC encoder implements only AAC LC.  The ffmpeg tool does handle muxing/demuxing but that is cleanly separated from the codec in a different library; the codecs are in libavcodec and the muxing/demuxing is in libavformat.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm pitching everything in an H.263 encoder (argb/PCM) so I'm focusing on the demuxing/decoding part. If AAC-LC frames can be extracted just like H.264/AVC frames with a for loop and some header and easily converted in a raw AAC stream, then hopefully that means I can use only the libavcodec part.

Comment: I wonder if I'll save time if I jump onto the  libavcodec v.51 r15261, which is mentioned in a 2008 post, and at that time was said to only support MAIN/LC as you told me.

Comment: There are some improvements in development here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2686

Comment: Still searching for the simplest, most specific code example of AAC-LC decoder. Thanks!

Comment: The MPEG standards are covered by numerous patents, and there is a have patent pool, and a single licensing organisation.  This is inherently incompatible with the GPL, and will have much of the open source community running away in horror. 

As for obtaining the standards:  You probably have to pay for them unless you have a tame academic library handy.

Comment: @Marko I certainly have nothing good to say about patents.  But they have nothing to do with whether a piece of software can be licensed under the GPL.  Copyright licenses != patent licenses.  The question specifically asked about AAC-LC, so any implementation will suffer from the patent issues you mentioned.  If you don't need to be compatible with AAC-LC specifically then by all means use a codec without a patent racket, such as Opus, Vorbis, or FLAC.